# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, yet argument appears to be of valid type

Tags: java, web-services, soap, glassfish, jax-ws

I have a jax-ws web service class with a web operation written as:

```
public String processIncomingMsg(int msgType, String senderCB, int receiveCB,
                int ussdOpType, String msIsdn, String serviceCode,
                int codeScheme, String ussdString,
                NamedParameterList extenionInfo) {
```

the service is deployed in the glassfish webserver so I have access to `http://localhost:8080/AppName/ReceiveUSSDNotifications?Tester` which is a form that is used to invoke the web service operation. When I enter receiveCB, one of the method parameters, as `0XFFFFFF`. I see "Cannot convert 0xFFFFFFFF in int" in the glassfish server logs and

```
WS00041: Service invocation threw an exception with message : null; Refer to the server log for more details
Exceptions details : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:342) 
at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:106) 
at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:157) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160) 
at ...
```

As the response (error log) from the browser. I wonder what could be going wrong because `0xffffff` is just a hex representation of an integer and so there shouldn't be a conversion problem.

Comment: how is `receiveiveCb` passed to your method? Are you sure it's  `0xFFFFFF` and not `"0xFFFFFF"` (a string representation). please add more code. a method prototype and a stack stack is really poor information for us to help.

Comment: I pass arguments to `processIncomingMsg` using a form located at `http://localhost:8080/AppName/ReceiveUSSDNotifications?Tester` `receiveCB` is just one of the many arguments I supply. There are other integer literals supplied as base 10 integers and they appear to be passed to the method as ints just fine.

Comment: still not enough informations.

Comment: I've supplied the method definition, invocation mechanism and two error log outputs, one from the console and one from the browser. I don't know what other information you could possibly need since you're not specifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post your full stacktrace here.

At face value, I would say your expectation is not realistic:

1. What you've supplied, for all intents and purposes is a `String` and by your operation definition, it's supposed to be converted to an int. The only way this could possibly happen is using some variant of `Integer.parseInt`, specifically the variant that converts hex to decimal,`Integer.parseInt(int, 16)`. Any other incarnation of that method will blow up with a `NumberFormatException`. How would the testing tool or JAXB know you're not providing a Base-10 format, to be using the right variant of `parseInt`? Not to mention the preceeding "0x" would make it nonconvertible anyway
2. Even if it somehow got converted, you'll find that [`Integer.MAX_VALUE== 2147483647`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE), which is less than `FFFFFF==4294967295`. Another `NumberFormatException`. What you should have there is a `long`

Comment: My assumption appears to be wrong. I know parameters passed from clients are normally passed as strings down to the applications but I thought that JAX-WS does the conversions to suitable types automatically. Also my assumption had been boosted by the fact that I passed some other `ints` (base 10) and the server did not flag them. I should mention that am new to JavaEE. This answer has given me a lot of insight. Thanks!

Comment: You mean you passed a regular (non-hex) integer as an argument and it worked, yeah? As in "6"? @Lym

Comment: Correct! I passed other "normal" integers and only the non-base 10 one was flagged.

Comment: Understood @Lym. If this answer sorts your issue out, don't forget to accept

Comment: Turns out the Service API manual had a typo. The wsdl declares `receiveCB` as a string. `0xffffffff` was out of range anyway since java uses 32-bits for `int` storage by default, a fact you hinted on but I had skipped over. Apologies for over commenting. Your answer did solve my problem.